# Symfony2 page cache - my code changes are ignored

Tags: symfony

I am trying symfony2, but no matter what code changes I make, they are ignored for about 30-60 seconds after I write them.

I tried to disable twig's cache, switched to php instead of twig, change app.php and app_dev.php, nothing.

The problems seems to be from symfony and not from templating engine, because if I make a new method and just write die('here') it's ignored for a while.

I am developing on a mac using mamp.

Comment: Technically, if you use app_dev.php to comunicate with your app, it shouldn't generate cache since you're on the dev enviroment. Try to check if mamp has some kind of internal cache

Comment: there is no caching enabled in mamp

Comment: What exact version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: latest, 2.3.5 installed via composer, not normal download

Comment: Well, half of the problem solved: switched to MAMP pro and it's fine. even a simple php script was affected.

Now the other half: what to use instead mamp & ampps?

Comment: Have you tried Xampp?

Comment: Not necessary anymore. I took the shortcut with Mamp pro :)